# Truth or myth to get white teeth?

Tags: medical-myths, hydrogen-peroxide, plaque, stain-removal-teeth

I've read in some forum that coconut oil or hydrogen peroxide could help to remove plaque and stains from teeth and will got white teeth. I know that teeth color is genetic thing but if they will have stains or plaque will this stuff would helpful ? So is it myth or truth ? Is there risk to use hydrogen peroxide ? When there was saying it'll help to have fresh breath.